# MAP estimation with hierarchical prior

Tags: map-estimation

I have a hierarchical prior with the probabilistic model as
$$p(Y,H,Z|G)=p(Y|H,Z)p(H|Z,G)p(Z|G)$$
and I was wondering if MAP estimation for H and Z together is possible here by maximizing the log probabilities? (all distributions in the RHS are known and Y and G are measured)

I feel it is possible as we can consider [H,Z] as the parameter to be estimated.

If so, is there a way to do it? For instance in optimisation, we do it one by one, maximize wrt H then Z per iteration and so on. Will it be similar here or can we do it simultaneously?

Comment: Why couldn't you just optimize the posterior?

Comment: The posterior is intractable in my case. one of the prior has a very complicated structure (adversarial regularisers)